# Restore picture file preview after imagemagick resize

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick

I used `mogrify -resize` on an image file and it removed the preview as you can see on the screenshot for IMG_2521.JPG:

[image]

How can I restore a preview? I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I have never tried but I believe you can do it with `jhead` and `-rgt` option and you may also need `-mkexif` https://www.sentex.ca/~mwandel/jhead/usage.html

Comment: `exiftool` can do it too https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4451.0

Comment: shouldn't the preview be generated automatically ? I don't think I should create another set of files

Comment: It's not another set of files. The thumbnail is actually embedded inside each original image. Did you use `-strip` in your `mogrify` command by the way? Also it's just a one-liner to regenerate all the thumbnails in all the files. Make a spare copy of a couple somewhere and go there and try `jhead -rgt IMG*.JPG` and failing that `jhead -mkexif -rgt IMG*.JPG`